# PloneFormGen Override Uppercase Output

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I am trying to figure out how to make the replacement parts fields data show up in all uppercase when the email is received. This form will be used for entering serial numbers containing alphanumeric characters which makes it hard to read when lowercase letters are used.

Is there an override that can accomplish this or will the mailer template need to be modified? How would you resolve this?

[image: Form in Question]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the field has the id 'replacement-parts', add a custom script adapter with the key code:

> request.form['replacement-parts'] = request.form.get('replacement-parts', '').upper())

Make sure it's above your mailer, as the action adapters are executed in folder-contents order.